# I want to import .xsl(ms excel) file in to myadmin (mysql db

Tags: mysql

I'm totaly new for mysql, I have phpmyadmin(cs4 mysql) on which **i have to import the excel file.**
plz help me,thanks in advance.I dont want to use command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a top row in the Excel file containing the corresponding columnnames in the MySQL table.

If that doesn't work, we need a bit more information; maybe some example data from your Excel file and the structure of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Save excel file as csv, import csv via phpMyAdmin

Comment: hello,
 thank u,But i did this method,no data added in table,plz specify step by step,thanks once again